# Cannot save input data into database

Tags: php, mysql

I already create coding for display output using multiple table, so I use Join function.
but I would like to add an extra column to insert note. When I clicked save button, the notes does save in the database.

-Here is the coding for JOIN query.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsearch']))
{
    $searchKul=$_POST['txtkul'];
    $searchSem=$_POST['txtsem'];

    if( $searchKul && $searchSem!= NULL)
    {
            $queryKul       =  "SELECT DISTINCT  _kursus.namakur_bm, _kursus.kodkursus, _kulliyah.kod_kul, kur_twr.sesi_sem, exm_penilaian.kod_skema                                                                                                        
                                FROM _kulliyah

                                JOIN _program ON _kulliyah.kod_kul = _program.kod_kul

                                JOIN kur_twr ON _program.kod_prog = kur_twr.kod_prog

                                JOIN _kursus ON kur_twr.kodkursus = _kursus.kodkursus

                                JOIN exm_penilaian ON _kursus.kodkursus = exm_penilaian.kodkursus

                                WHERE _kulliyah.kod_kul LIKE '%$searchKul%'

                                AND kur_twr.sesi_sem LIKE '%$searchSem%'

                                ORDER BY kodkursus";

            $rsKul               = mysql_query($queryKul);
            $row_rsKul           = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsKul);
            $totalRows_rsKul     = mysql_num_rows($rsKul);
```

- This is for coding note

  if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
                  {
                      $txtadd = $_POST['txtadd'];

  ```
                  $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO _kursus(remark) VALUES('$txtadd')");

                  if($result)
                  {
                          echo ("<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Succesfully INSERT data!');</script>
                                 <script language='JavaScript'>window.location='kul7.php';</script>"); 
                  }
                  else 
                  {
                          echo 'PLEASE ENTER AGAIN'; 
                  }
              }?>
              <form action="" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="txtadd"/><input type="submit" name="btnsave" value="SAVE"/>
              </form>
              <?php 
              "</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
              }
                  while($row_rsKul = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsKul));
              {
                  echo "</table></center>";
              }
              mysql_close();
              }
          }
  ```

---

```
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO _kursus(remark) VALUES('$txtadd')");
```

the above query seem like did not function. I cannot save data to database. when I click button 'save' nothing happen..

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Never EVER assume a query succeeds. always check for errors. `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`. then assume that your site is going to be attacked by screaming hordes of crazy attackers bent on world takeover, and program accordingly. Right now you're just begging to get your server pwn3d via sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_rsInsert = "INSERT INTO _kursus (remark) VALUES ('$txtadd')
                   WHERE _kursus.kodkursus = " .$_POST['kodkursus'];
```

- I change coding as above but the query does not function. 
  I want to do something like when user add note, the note will be save in the database based on code appear.